# Change date format before validation

Tags: laravel

I have to change the date format before validation.

I use the german date format (dd.mm.yyyy). But for the validation i need the format yyyy-mm-dd.

here my rules from the requests file:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title'     => 'required|min:5',
            'start'     => 'required|date_format:d.m.Y|after:+1 week|unique:talks,start',
            'end'       => 'required|date_format:d.m.Y|after:start|unique:talks,end',
            'interval'  => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

Now i found this function:

```
public function all()
    {
        $input = parent::all();

        //modify input here

        return $input;
    }
```

But how can i modify the input here???

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does it mean you need the format for validation? Your input is already being validated in your Request. Your current validation uses the german date format, as can be seen in your code. Do you need to know how to change the validation in this request to use the yyyy-mm-dd format?

Comment: In the database i use a date field (yyyy-mm-dd), but in the requests file i get the german format, so i can´t use _unique:talks,start_. Before i can validate the date from input against the date in the database, i have to change the format. I found the solution with the function all(), but i can`t found the right syntax to change the input. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$input` variable is just an associative array with key -> value pairs of the request input. You can directly modify the array:

```
public function all()
    {
        $input = parent::all();

        $input['start'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($input['start']));
        $input['end'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($input['end']));

        return $input;
    }
```

This will translate your date values for the purposes of validation. Because the validator calls the `all()` method.

However, this does not modify the original values in your input.

Whenever you access the input values by a different method than `all()`, the original value will appear. E.g. `$request->input('start')` will give you the original German format but `$request->all()['start']` will give you the translated international formal.

Such a situation is a potential source of bugs and it's hard to maintain. The right solution for your problem is to write a tiny custom middleware that will modify the request values. See here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-modify-input-before-validation?page=2

Comment: many thanks, I think that is the right solution for me. I need the u.s. date format only for checking the rules like here: `'start'     => 'required|date_format:d.m.Y|after:+1 week|unique:talks,start'`, in my Model i change the date format anyway